# Could principle component decomposed coordinates value be correlated to each other?

Tags: correlation, dimensionality-reduction, pca

I am wondering if we have a **`A= n*p`** matrix of samples and we run a PC decomposition on it.

Say the eigenvector matrix is **E**, so the samples in the eigenvector space should be

> B= A*(E)^-1

So, I am wondering if there is any rule that the columns of B to be correlated? That is, the first PC loadings and the second PC loadings to be correlated?
 Thanks!

Comment: In addition to answers, I would like to point that one of the goals of PCA is to get uncorrelated coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

PCs are calculated based on eigenvectors (e1 nad e2 in your case) of correlation or covariance matrix. Eigenvectors are orthogonal, so PCs are uncorrelated. If you would like to check the proof, you can find it on page 432 in *Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis 6th edition* written by Richard A. Johnson and Dean W. Wichern.

Answer (score 0):

They should be uncorrelated. Just think of a simple example, where you have two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$, which are 100% correlated. If you run PCA on those, what would be the outcome? Well, you'd get the first principal component $\tilde x_1$, which would be some linear combination of your original variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ absorbing all the fluctuations and a second component which is always zero.

Comment: Sorry I need to revise my question, I mean the coordinate on the new PC coordinate system ( like in your example, it probably will become (x1,0) on direction (1,1) and (1,-1)